# Flash a binary for Arduino Due board from Atmel studio

Tags: arduino, atmel, arduino-ide

I am working on Arduino Due board. I need to interface a module to this board using SPI protocol.
I have a source code which i build in Atmel studio project . Now i need to flash this binary (.hex/.srec) on Arduino Due board.
For that i installed an add-on Visual Micro for Atmel studio . But still it require some JTAG (like SAM ICE )for Flashing.
Can i do this flashing without using any JTAG.
I have tried installing the Arduino IDE also. But am not able to use the Atmel studio project in that.
How can i flash this binary on Arduino Due  ? Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you do not require JTAG to flash Arduino sketches.
The Arduino IDE can upload sketches through the USB interface.

In Arduino IDE look at Tools -> Board/Serial Port and select your serial arduino due programming port.
If it is not available you need the driver.
You need to connect the Due through the micro USB slot directly next to the power socket (the other one is native USB).

If you wish to debug the SAM3x you need a JTAGICE3 or SAM-ICE hardware (I read somewhere the latest version of Atmel studio might support debugging through USB but no idea).
It's around 100 USD and the SAM-ICE is the better one to choose if you want more software support.
You do not want to use JTAG. There is a JTAG header on the Due but that's pretty useless (someone correct me if mistaken).
Instead of the bulky 10 pins you will be fine with a total of 5 pins, debugging through the SWD connector (4 pins) plus 3.3V (Vtarget) will be fully functional and fast (12mhz high data throughput).

However, maybe start with Arduino sketches through the IDE.
Once you got started you can look into debugging.